# Pi approximation with Archimedes equation

Tags: c, pi

I ve to create a pi approximation based on Archimedes equation. I ve to do so with for mode and recursive mode. In for mode i ve create sth like the above:

```
  double Pi_approximation(double r, double L){

   int i;
   double fin;
   double y;

   for(i=1; i<4; i++){

           y =sqrt(2*((r*r) - r*(sqrt(4*((r*r) - (L)))))); 

           L = y;
           printf("%f \n", L);
   }

   return y;
}
```

My problem is in second loop of for. In the first y is calculated normally but in second loop when i print y and L, it prints me their pointer!! Any idea?

Comment: Could you add an example of the output you're getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to be sure what is happening, but I will take a guess anyway! Most likely the value you pass to one of the `sqrt()` calls is negative. When this happens, `y` (and hence `L`) will be `NaN`. The output then will be compiler dependent. For example on my compiler the output is:

```
-1.#IND00
```

Comment: 1.414241
-1.#IND00
-1.#IND00
-1.#IND00

Comment: Which is the correspond symbol of NaN in C?

Comment: That confirms my guess. You just need to work out what you've done wrong that has led to you passing a negative value to `sqrt()`.

Comment: Xm you answer my question. Thank you David!

Answer (score 0):

you probably corrupted the code with memory leaks or similar in some other part...
The code alone seems to work.